# Html element not covering 100% height

Tags: html, css

I want this element to cover 100% of the screen height, obviously not doing as so, any fixes?
I see that the div is 100% height of the section which is 100% of the body which is set as 100%.

```html
<body>
    <section id="Block1">
        <div class="firstsection">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo magnam iusto quibusdam quas reiciendis fugit architecto consequatur similique distinctio dolore repudiandae rem illo alias iure sunt eos culpa, amet consectetur!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

***CSS***

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.firstsection {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    text-align: center;
}
#Block1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: use `vh` or`vw` CSS units, like `100vh`

Answer (score 0):

Use this for body:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height and width 100% also for html,

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

you can additionally use `vh vw` dimensions to set width and height on the whole screen

```
#Block1 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why no one is adding a snippet? `body {height: 100vh;}`

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.firstsection {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    text-align: center;
}
#Block1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="Block1">
        <div class="firstsection">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo magnam iusto quibusdam quas reiciendis fugit architecto consequatur similique distinctio dolore repudiandae rem illo alias iure sunt eos culpa, amet consectetur!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```